# Cannot Access file server via IP Address but it can be accessed by its hostname

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

i have shared a folder in windows server 2003. while accessing that server via \server-ip-address from another server (windows 2003) i am getting an error saying "You might not have permission to use this network resource. .. There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"
But via \server-hostname i can access the server.

What would be the issue ?

Comment: Double check the WINS configuration on both servers (ipconfig /all)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue is that there are no logon servers available to service the logon request ;-)

Are your domain controllers up, and can both servers see them?

Comment: if i do \\domainname then i can access it.

Comment: but if i do \\domainname-ipaddress then password prompts.

Comment: You get a password prompt? I thought you said you get an error saying there are no logon servers available? What do you mean by \\domainname-ipaddress? Are you using the DNS name or the IP address? Please be clear in your explanation of the problem.

Comment: sorry for the unclear, let me start, no logon servers available error is coming when client1 (server 2003) tries to access client2 (server 2003) via \\client2-ipaddress. but client1 can access client2 by its hostname \\client2. From client1 and client2 it can access its domain controller (server 2008) via its hostname \\server but password prompts while accessing \\server-ipaddress (IP Address of domain controller).

Comment: Are the machines joined to the domain? Have they lost their trust relationship? Check the security event logs for failure audits.

Comment: from eventvwr i am seeing "There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper" error . source:userenv eventid 1053. client1 and client2 are joined to the domain. I am trying to connect the share folder \\client2 or client2-ipaddress from local user (local administrator user).

Comment: Hi, we found that the rpc dynamic ports are not opened in firewall from client1/2 to the server (domain controller) . will this be the cause of the problem mentioned above. also i tired rejoining the domain for client1/2 and it fails saying no rpc server found.

Comment: I have a feeling you are connecting via IPv6 when you use \\client1 and IPv4 when you use \\client1-ip try and connect using \\client1-ipv6

Answer (score -1):

Goto services.msc and start the "ComputerBrowser" service and All Network related services. it works for me.